# Total curvature/Turning Number/Winding Number of simple curve

Tags: differential-geometry, polar-coordinates, curvature, winding-number

I am totally confused by the various notions and formulas for Total curvature/Turning Number/Winding Number of plane curves.

I did some calculations for the curve $\alpha(\phi)=(r(\phi),\phi)$ in polar coordinates
with $r(\phi)=(2\cos(4\phi))^{1/4}$.

My result until now is contrary to theory and a glance on the graph the value 2.5

Has anyone a different/correct result ?

Answer (score 2):

The total curvature should be $5\pi$. The curve consists of four lobes, each traversed counterclockwise as $\phi$ increases. There is no winding number, per se, as the curve crosses through the origin numerous times. (Note that $\phi\in [-\pi/8,\pi/8]\cup[3\pi/8,5\pi/8]\cup[7\pi/8,9\pi/8]\cup[11\pi/8,13\pi/8]$.)

*EDIT*: The tangent turns through $\pi/4 + \pi = 5\pi/4$ on each of the four lobes, so the total curvature is in fact $5\pi$. This gives a surprising result because of the singular nature of the curve.

[image]

If we imagine smoothing the points of the curve at the origin and having the curve go smoothly from $\phi = \pi/8$ to $3\pi/8$, etc., then the smoothly-varying tangent turns through $-3\pi/4$ each time. Thus, the total curvature of the given curve $-3\pi$ gives us the usual $2\pi$ for a simple closed, smooth curve, traversed counterclockwise. That is, the total curvature of the given curve is, indeed, $5\pi$.

Comment: Can you tell how you did calculate $8\pi$ ? The graph seems to show me that the turning number is 3. The winding number I calculated as queer 0.5

Comment: I didn't :) I know that we get a total curvature of $2\pi$ when we go counterclockwise around a simple closed (piecewise smooth) curve and a total curvature of $-2\pi$ when we go clockwise. It is a standard result that $\int k\,ds$ gives the angle through which the tangent vector of the curve rotates when you around the curve. What winding number did you calculate? The graph has *four* lobes, not *three*.

Comment: Please look at the graph. The tangent turns 3 times around when starting through the counterclock loop - if I see correctly. I am very interested in a formal calculation.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Because of the singularities at the origin, you're right, of course. The tangent vector turns through $\pi/4 + \pi = 5\pi/4$ on each lobe. See my edit.